# Генерация веб-страницы с помощью cgi python

Tags: python, python-3.x, html5, cgi

у меня такая задача: проверить последовательность битов на бит четности, я хочу это сделать с помощью регулярного выражения. Когда я написал паттерн и, вообще, если написать любую строчку кода, то перестает работать скрипт, выводя ошибку 500. Комментируя паттерн или строчки кода, скрипт работает. Я пока что закомментировал проверку и пытаюсь вывести что-то
[image: Паттерн и код закомментированы]
[image: Число выводится, скрипт работает]
[image: Паттерн раскоментирован]
[image: Ошибка 500]

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Parity Bit</title>
 </head>
<body>
  <form method="POST" action="1.py">
    <input type="text" name="bit">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

скрипт:

```
import cgi
import re
#bitPattern = compile('^([0-1][0-1][0-1][0-1][0-1][0-1][0-1][0-1])$')
data = cgi.FieldStorage()
bit = data.getvalue('bit')
print('Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n')
print('<!DOCTYPE HTML>')
print('<html lang="en">')
print('<head> <meta charset="UTF-8">')
print('<title>Python Response</title> </head>')
print('<body>')
'''if bitPattern.match(bit) != None:
    print('<h3>', bit, '</h3>')
else:
    print('<h3>Неверный ввод</h3>')'''
print('<h3>', bit, '</h3>')
print('<a href="1.html">Back</a>')
print('</body>')
print('</html>')
```

Comment: Ну, в закомментированной строчке вы пытаетесь использовать функцию `compile` которая не существует

Comment: Либо добавить `from re import compile`, либо писать полное имя `re.compile`

Comment: А, как вы понимаете, что такое бит четности?

Comment: Кстати, в регекспах же есть повторение, зачем копипастить один шаблон, если можно написать, сколько раз его использовать. Если не путаю будет `[0-1]{8}`, но точно не помню